# How to justify the text of a TextBlock in a Windows Phone application?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, textblock

I want to put a justify text into a textblock but gives me an error. Why? Can i resolve?

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <TextBlock Height="220" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Margin="102,174,0,0" 
               Name="textBlock1" 
               Text="TextBlock sdfg asfgbfgb  adf ab afg g " 
               TextAlignment="Justify"
               VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               Width="255" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: It might help if you said what the error is you are receiving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, when using TextAlignment="Justify" in a TextBlock, the windows phone application unexpectedly exits. This happened a lot and after a little research, I found out that this is a bug. And I see no work-arounds either.

Comment: There's no way to put a text justified?

Comment: FYI: on "VS2012 for WP" when you set TextAlignment=Justify, then the Designer highlights this property as having an error and error tooltip says: `Specified method is not supported`

Answer (score 8):

You need to use a `<RichTextBox>` and it will be great.

```
<RichTextBox TextAlignment="Justify">
    <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit." />
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

If you want, [here is a french tutorial from Rudy Huyn](http://www.rudyhuyn.com/blog/2011/11/08/comment-justifier-du-texte-sous-windows-phone/).

Answer (score 1):

Use the Richtextbox to justify text and bind value at runtime to it,

In .xaml

```
                <RichTextBox TextAlignment="Justify"
                             IsReadOnly="True"
                             Margin="0,0,0,10">
                    <Paragraph Foreground="#626262"
                               FontSize="17"
                               FontStyle="Normal"
                               FontFamily="Regular"  >
                        <Run x:Name="txtDescription" />
                    </Paragraph>
                </RichTextBox>
```

and in .xaml.cs

```
 txtDescription.Text ="TextBlock sdfg asfgbfgb  adf ab afg g";
```